# Enable Ping in Windows Server Firewall?

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, monitoring, ping, windows

I've just installed Windows Server 2008 on a server and I'm able to connect through Remote Desktop but can't ping. Do I need to open an special port on the firewall to be able to ping a server?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

By default Windows 2008 does not respond to pings. To enable:

> Administrative Tools
>
> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
>
> Inbound Rules
>
> File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-IN)
>
> Enable Rule

[image]

You should now be able to ping your server from the LAN.

Comment: What about IPv6? Won't someone please think of IPv6!?!

Comment: I can add that to allow ping from outside the subnet I had to enable "All profiles" for the rule, not only "public".

Comment: Yeah. that is the most stupid goruping ever - File and printer sharing for ICMP ;) Got stumbled over that one, too ;) Everyone I tell that laughs.

Comment: What is more dumb is that the rule is disabled for the Domain profile, but enabled for Public and Private profiles.  Surely most Domain profiles are on networks with a higher existing level of security than those you might deem Private or even Public...

Comment: @MarkBrackett perhaps you are good by now. Nevertheless default Scope for this rule limits things to *Local subnet*. Change it to any, and you'd be able to ping with ICMPv6 you PC from outside your WAN.

Answer (score 12):

Enable ping through the Windows Firewall at the command line like so:

```
netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8
```

Apparently this has changed in Windows Server 2008 R2 and newer, to:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request"
    protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

That's.. uh... quite a mouthful.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737845(WS.10).aspx has the list of all the values, search for "set icmpsetting" within the page.

Answer (score 9):

in powershell you can use :

```
# allow-icmp.ps1
# Sets up windows firewall to allow inbound ICMP - using PowerShell
# Thomas Lee - tfl@psp.co.uk

#create firewall manager object
$FWM=new-object -com hnetcfg.fwmgr

# Get current profile
$pro=$fwm.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile

# Check Profile
if ($pro.IcmpSettings.AllowInboundEchoRequest) {
    "Echo Request already allowed"
} else {
    $pro.icmpsettings.AllowInboundEchoRequest=$true
}

# Display ICMP Settings
"Windows Firewall - current ICMP Settings:"
"-----------------------------------------"
$pro.icmpsettings
```

Comment: Nice.  +1 for PowerShell goodness.

Answer (score 8):

You will want to allow ICMP packets through.  Ping doesn't use TCP, so there is no port to open.

Comment: The fact that "ping doesn't use TCP" is a little misleading.  Since there are other protocols that use ports, it's perhaps more useful to say "ping uses ICMP, which is a portless, layer-3 protocol, so you enable ICMP to allow ping, not open a port".  Some firewalls allow you to filter message type, so you need to allow "echo request" and "echo response" to allow ping to work.

Comment: er, "...to allow ping to work if you didn't want to otherwise allow all message types for some reason".

Answer (score 5):

Run these 2 in admin powershell, it enables both ipv6 and ipv4 inbound pings on all networks (public/private/domain):

```
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" -enabled True
Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv6-In)" -enabled True
```

It is equivalent to this https://serverfault.com/a/6049/147813

Answer (score 2):

Another way of fixing this:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

Comment: While that works, it adds a rule, as opposed to enabling the 'baked in' rule.  This could lead to confusion (the baked-in rule not being enabled, yet ICMP still working because of the added rule, when attempting to account-for or predict the FW behaviour).  However, it could still be useful if you wanted to allow ICMP only for a particular network profile (eg. only for domain) since the baked-in rule targets all profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to use the correct quotation marks. Some web sites replace the quotation marks by similar symbols which cause syntax errors. C.f. [enter link description here](http://blog.mediawhole.com/2010/01/enable-icmp-echo-ping-in-windows-server.html)