# Ping, firewall or DNS issue on Win Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, ping

I've installed windows server 2008 as a VM for the developers here to work on. Installed SQL Server 2008 as well as IIS7.

I am not quite sure why, I can remote into that machine using the name I gave to it (winserverdev) but the guys that are supposed to use the bloody thing can't.

One very interesting thing is that I can connect but I can't ping... not the name nor the IP address.

Is there anything that I should be looking in order to make it work?

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks heaps in advance, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that you have the firewall on and are probably blocking ICMP. ICMP echo requests (pings) are not a prerequisite for connectivity. Since that is taken care of - on to your main issue.

As for why you can connect and they can not - we need more info. I'm assuming you are all on the same internal network and there is nothing different about your connection than theirs. Are the other users' accounts added to the Remote Desktop allow list?

Comment: We are all in the same internal network (novell) and I created one user with Admin permissions for them... I use the same just to install anything they want and stuff.. the computer hosting the VM is right next to me and I have no problems with the name. What I can't understand is why my computer can resolve the name and theirs can't...

I will check the firewall thing now... thanks for the explanation mate. Hope I will success at some stage!

Comment: Beat me to it! See here for enabling ping: http://serverfault.com/questions/6046/enable-ping-in-windows-server-firewall and here for enabling other users for Remote Desktop: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_Windows_Server_2008_Remote_Desktop_Administration#Controlling_Remote_Desktop_Access

Comment: awesome... cheers Grizly!!!

Comment: @Fred - How are you "resolving" the name? Is there a DNS entry for it? If there is, what does nslookup or dig tell you about the A record for it? Do you and the devs use the same DNS server? Are you and the devs on different subnets? etc? The more details you can give us about the differences, the better.

Comment: we are all in a massive network... all of us connecting to the same DHCP and DNS servers... the network is novell... my IP range, DNS servers, DHCP are the same as the devs... well, at least it looks like the same when I get the info from ipconfig /all. I didn't add the name and IP into my HOSTS file. I think my computer is resolving by itself haha but not theirs. I had to add the ip and name into their hosts file in order to get it going. For now, it's working. Am I happy with that? no. Running out of ideas but I really appreciate your help MarkM

Comment: @Fred - Is it self registering its DNS record? If it isn't, or if dynamic updates are disallowed on your network, have one of your network guys make an A record for it on your internal DNS servers. Like I suggested earlier, you can verify whether or not this is the issue by using dig or nslookup.

Answer (score 0):

What operating systems are the other users using. If it's Vista or Windows 7 then it could have something to do with Network Discovery, it could be turned off on their machines. I would also check Network Discovery on the server. Also have a look at "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security". I normally turn the Domain Firewall off (depends on the situation).

Are their any shares on the server? Can they see them?

Check rpc connectivity with RPC ping tool: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831051

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to work in other direction try to ping from VM machine to your IP and to your team mates who cant connect.

Check if the network for VM machine is setup to be bridged or NAT or otherway?