# hyper v guest windows 2008 SP2 unreachable from intranet

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, guest

I have got strange problem with windows 2008 guest. Network for this host is configured as external. I am able to ping FROM this host and I am unable to ping to THIS host. When I am resetting connection at this guest system from network connections I can ping this host for few seconds. Where is the problem? This machine uses static address.

Answer (score 0):

The same network configuration requirements of a real machine apply to virtual machines. Do you have a default gateway configured? Perhaps you could elaborate on exactly how your VM, host, etc have their NICs configured.

Comment: On hyper v server runs three virtual machines. All guest except this one works perfect. The problematic host is able to be pinged only for a while when network connection is resetting (on this problematic guest). All ip configration seems to be ok

Comment: Updated integration components installed on the guest? Host hardware on the [compatibility list](http://www.windowsservercatalog.com/)?

Comment: It is ML 350 G5 (HP) integration disk is installed, all components are checked

Comment: Do any of your VMs have Legacy Network Interfaces?

Comment: All my VMs using normal network adapters. I tries on problematic machine using legacy but there was the same problem - I was able to ping other machines and other machine were able to ping problematic machine only for few seconds when connection was resetting

Comment: You've got me, sounds like an issue with the OS on the guest machine. Anything in the event log? Firewall? Error messages?

Comment: First I still didn't resolve that issue (5 houres). Firewall is disabled, in event log there is no information (I checked on host ang guest). I tried to reconnect to other built in server Ethernet port but there is same issue - can ping other machines but other machines cant ping me and cant access my services (for 10-15 sec can when I am resetting network card)

Answer (score 0):

Are you pinging machine name and/or IP address?

Is Network Discovery enabled? By default it is not enabled. I would say this is the most likely root cause.

Also, look at this post: [Enable Ping in Windows Server Firewall?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6046/enable-ping-in-windows-server-firewall)

Based on: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-network-discovery , I would say that the custom status may warrant further investigation.

> **Custom**
>
> This is a mixed state in which some
>   settings related to network discovery
>   are enabled, but not all of them. For
>   example, network discovery could be
>   turned on, but you or your system
>   administrator might have disabled a
>   firewall exception that affects
>   network discovery.
>
> Network discovery requires that the
>   dnscache, fdrespub, ssdpsrv, and
>   upnphost services are started, that
>   the Windows Firewall exception for
>   network discovery is enabled, and that
>   other firewalls are not interfering
>   with network discovery. If some but
>   not all of these are true, the network
>   discovery state will be shown as
>   Custom.

Comment: 1) I use ip addresses 2) network discovery is enabled, but status is "Custom"

Comment: Does the problem go away when the Firewall is completely disabled?

Comment: I completely disabled firewall on all machines and clients in my network. Pinging works only when I am resetting connection on problematic virtual machine

Comment: You probably should think about doing some packet sniffing and some other network diagnostics to narrow the point of failure. Does the machine receive the ICMP traffic? Does it send a reply?

Comment: when I scan network gateway is visible 10.10.9.1, it is gateway to problematic guest 10.10.9.3